# How to view RecyclerView items sorted by ID?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app i have something like a menu that load data stored in `SharedPreferences` to a *Constructor* and build from it 2 `RecyclerView's`.

Now i want to make that if i press an button from the bottom `recyclerView` like "*CICCIO*" that has in it constructor item like *ID set by 1 i would that in the other `recyclerView` where there are a lot of colored buttons to be visualized just button's that have also ID set by 1* in their constructor but i'm not very in to android and i can't get how can i make a "*sort method*" like that.

I have yet the `onClick` method set on bottom `RecyclerView` and i have yet method's `getID` from the **bottom** `recyclerView` constructor and `getID` from the **top** `RecyclerView`.

[ACTIVITY SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD8XK.png)

And here is the code from my activity:

```
//  Builder del BOTTOM recyclerView
public void buildRecyclerViewMenu(){
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMenu);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerViewMenu recyclerViewMenu = new RecyclerViewMenu(menuConstructors);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewMenu);

    recyclerViewMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewMenu.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {

        }
    });

}

// Builder del TOP recyclerView
public void buildRecyclerView(){
    mRecyclerViewBOT = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerViewBOT.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
    Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(items);
    mRecyclerViewBOT.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerViewBOT.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final int position) {

        }
    });

}
```

While here are the method's where i load data to Bottom and top RecyclerView

```
private void loadDataMenu(){
    new ArrayList<MenuConstructor>();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MENU_SAVE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("menu list",null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MenuConstructor>>() {}.getType();
    menuConstructors = gson.fromJson(json, type );

    if(menuConstructors == null){

        menuConstructors = new ArrayList<>();
        Toast.makeText(cassa.this,"NESSUN TASTO DA VISUALIZZARE" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}

private void loadDataTasti(){
    new ArrayList<Item>();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("TASTI_SAVE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("tasti list",null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>() {}.getType();
    items = gson.fromJson(json, type );

    if(items == null){

        items = new ArrayList<>();
        Toast.makeText(cassa.this,"NESSUN TASTO DA VISUALIZZARE" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

While here is my Item.java that is the model class of TOP recycler View:

public class Item {

```
private int menu;

private String tipo;

private String codice;

private String deskT;

private String deskS;

private String sfondo;

private String font;

private String qta;

private double pre;



Item(int id, String typo, String codice_t, String desk_T,String desk_S,String sfondo_c,String font_c,String quant,double prezzo){
    menu = id;
    tipo = typo;
    codice = codice_t;
    deskT = desk_T;
    deskS = desk_S;
    sfondo = sfondo_c;
    font = font_c;
    qta = quant;
    pre = prezzo;
}

public int getMenu(){return menu;}

public String getTipo(){return tipo;}

public String getCodice(){return codice;}

public String getDeskT(){return deskT;}

public String getDeskS(){return deskS;}

public String getSfondo(){return sfondo;}

public String getFont(){return font;}

public String getQuant(){return qta;}

public double getPrice(){return pre;}
```

}

And here is the model of MenuConstructor (bottom recyclerView)

public class MenuConstructor {

```
    int id;

    private String deskT;

    private String sfondo;

    private String font;

            MenuConstructor(int idID,String Desk,String Sfondo,String Font){
                id = idID;
                deskT = Desk;
                sfondo = Sfondo;
                font = Font;
    }


    public int getBtnID(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getDesk(){
        return deskT;
    }

    public String getSfondoColor(){
        return sfondo;
    }

    public String getFontColor(){
        return font;
    }
```

}

so i want to compare the id from MenuConstructor with menu (id) from the Item.java and show just item with a certain ID.

Comment: You can using `Collections.sort` to resolve your issue.
 But I don't know about your model class which using for your adapter, can you provide it?i

Comment: @gianhtran added modelclass of top recyclerView the bottomRecyclerView model is almost the same

Comment: I got it, so please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a new ArrayList and comparing the item.getMenu() with menuConstructors.getBtnID() in a for cycle which scrolls for the same lenght of the ArrayList.

```
  recyclerViewMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewMenu.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {

                Toast.makeText(cassa.this,String.valueOf(menuConstructors.get(position).getBtnID()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ArrayList<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for(Item item : items) {

                    if(item.getMenu() == menuConstructors.get(position).getBtnID() ) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }

                mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using Collections.sort()

```
private List<Item> getSortedItems(List<Item> items) {
    Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Item item, Item nextItem) {
            return ComparisonChain.start()
                    .compare(item.getMenu(), nextItem.getMenu())
                    .result();
        }
    });
    return items;
}
```

this method will return the `item list` sort by `menu`

hope this helps

Comment: Actually the Item is an ArrayList and if i'm not wrong this will compare the items and just sort them by ID when i want to compare items from 2 different models and show just item's that have value in MENU that equals to value set in ID (i've added also the other model)

Comment: I mean i click "CICCIO" that has ID 1 and in top recyclerView there have to be visible button's that has just MENU set by 1

Comment: so first at all, you should filter your items by your condition, after that, sort it by above method, and you can using ArrayList instead of List if you want